# V-text does not update after new firebase values are added

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

Using firebase and vuejs I need to load a post. That post contains comments that those comments were made by a user (recognizable by the user_uid) of whom we need to know the nickname, stored in the users/"user_uid" folder.

My firebase database structure looks like this:

```
posts
    randompostid1
         user_uid: postmaker,
         content: "examples"
         comments:
                 randomcommentid123
                       text: "Comment example"
                       user_uid: commenter
                 randomcommentid99
                       text: "another comment example"
                       user_uid: anothercommenter


users
     commenter <-------------------- commenter userid
         email: email@gmail.com
         nickname: "Mr commenter"
     postmaker<--------------------anotheruserid
         email: email@gmail.com
         nickname: "Mr post-maker"
     anothercommenter <------------ another commenter userid
         email: example@google.com
         nickname: "another commenter"
```

To retrieve all the post information we first read the post (e.g randompostid1). Then we will have a dictionary of comments with user_uid's of whom we need to retrieve the nickname. I use a for_loop to loop through the uid's to get the adaquate nicknames.  See code below:

```
watch: {
   comments: function(val){
      if (val != ""){
         for (let key in val){
            db.ref("users/" + val[key].uid).once("value").then(function(snapshot){
            val[key]["nickName"] = snapshot.val().nickname
            })
          }
       }
     }
  }
```

Then I try to display the nickname in a v-text element. The logging function simply logs the value of "comments". Note: "comments" is passed as a prop.

```
  <div class='comment' v-for='comment in comments'>
   <div class='uid' v-text='comment.nickName'></div>
   <div class='text' v-text='comment.text'></div>
   <button @click='logging'>button</button>
  </div>
```

The nickName will be shown as undefined in the v-text, but in "logging()" it will be included in the logged value of comments. Why is the "nickName" undefined in the v-text, even though it is defined when "comments" is logged?
Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: 
Solved by comment.
The line

```
 val[key]["nickName"] = snapshot.val().nickname
```

should be replaced by

```
 this.$set(val[key], "nickName", snapshot.val().nickname)
```

Comment: I suspect this is due to adding the `nickName` property dynamically. See the documentation on [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).